# Unable to mount F2FS partitions

Tags: linux, fedora, mount, sd-card, f2fs

I installed the f2fs-tools package in my Fedora system. I created a f2fs partition using mkfs.f2fs on my sdcard, but now I'm unable to use it.

The system is unable to mount automatically nor manually the partition.

Does anyone have some insight in what I may be doing wrong or not doing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the Fedora maintainers still insist not to compile F2FS kernel module, so you cannot use your SD Card on Fedora.

However, that doesn't mean you cannot compile it as kernel module. You can follow the instructions in [this link](http://www.gabrielemerli.com/?p=1653) or [this link](http://forum.fedoraonline.it/viewtopic.php?pid=207204) (how's your spanish? :) ) to compile and use the f2fs module.

Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't knew that Fedora do not use that module. PS: the links are in Italian.

Comment: Is this still true?

Comment: same on ubuntu 5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2